# When is an analog signal being produced when listening on a Bluetooth device sourced from Windows

Tags: audio, analog, interference, windows

When troubleshooting a buzzing noise from my Windows laptop while listening on Bluetooth headphones, it made me curious why there was even an analog signal being produced. I only get this high-pitched noise when connected to my laptop, the headphones sound great when connected to other sources.

I am looking for some insight into when a possible analog signal is being created, and why. Is it possible that the audio drivers are accommodating a process which creates an analog signal that it must mix in with the other audio sources? That doesn't make much sense to me though. I've disabled all the mics, all other sound outputs except my headphones. Is it possible that my audio driver will always produce an analog signal to accommodate my laptop's headphone jack?

Comment: There is no way to get an analog signal through USB, and it is astronomically unlikely that your system connects a DAC to a ADC just to transmit audio digitally.

Comment: Since I'm connecting via a bluetooth device, is USB related to the issue? Also, what do you think would cause buzzing if there an analog signal is not being produced at any point?

Comment: There are two ways that a Bluetooth transceiver connects to a system: USB and UART. And UART is only used in embedded systems and SoCs.

Comment: The buzzing would be caused by a digital issue, either in the OS/software or in the transceiver.

Comment: I'm way off track then, obviously I'm knowledgeable in this area. Thanks for the feedback, no pun intended. :).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams transceiver: unlikely/impossible. Bluetooth audio has both source and channel coding. Under no circumstances would you get a buzzing by transmission problems. This isn't FM radio.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I agree with you on the unlikely part, but it could be caused by a bug in the A2DP encoding firmware.

Comment: having worked a bit with audio codecs: nope; or, that would be a problem so persistent, that it wouldn't work better with other audio encodings potentially used by the other devices that work well with the headphones.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you think the issue is more likely that the headphones are having issues interpreting the audio over the laptop producing a quality audio output?

Comment: @AnotherDeveloper please staaaahp. I've told you what I think 3 (in words: THREE) times now. I won't change it, no matter how many times you ask. I applaud you to your dedication to the scientific method, but repeating the experiment "ask Marcus whether another reason than software generating noise on your Windows is likely" will not yield new insight.

Comment: This is a repair problem at best, a nightmare at worst. VTC.

Answer (score 2):

The analog signal only comes into existence in your headphones. Full stop.

So, since the headphones work with other devices: you haven't successfully eliminated all programs that add noise to your audio output. That's a pure software/usage problem, and unrelated to electrical engineering.

Bluetooth is standardized. Either audio transmission works, or it doesn't.

Comment: Do you know why I only have this issue when connecting to my laptop? Maybe the problem is how my headphones are interpreting the digital output from the laptop?

Comment: No. Stop looking around. Your problem is in software running on your PC. Not anything to do with Electrical Engineering

Comment: @AnotherDeveloper more likely the laptop is radiating EMI that is being picked up by the headphones.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok, if you are confident that the buzzing, high-pitched noise is a software issue, my question doesn't belong here. Sorry.

Comment: @AnotherDeveloper as Trevor said, it might be interference by the laptop, but that would vary with distance/relative position to laptop, whereas the payload audio wouldn't. Since you're not mentioning that: yes, my stochastic view on this is: it's software.